# Changing displayed data in a GUI without having redisplay the GUI

Tags: autohotkey

Is it possible to change the displayed data in a Gui without re displaying the entire GUI. I know I can change the data or text in controls but that is a somewhat unreliable method for long strings of data.

I have a small AHK script that initializes a serial device. The serial device occasionally does something unexpected when it starts up. I need to see the device initialization messages when it does not start up properly.

A second AHK script starts the Serial Init script then waits for the initialization to complete by watching for the Serial Init Gui window to be destroyed when the device initialization procedure has been completed properly.

I have to destroy the Serial Init Gui first then remake it when a new data string is received from the serial port.

The Second script that watches for the Serial Init Gui to be destroyed sees the Gui disappear when the text changes and carries on with the rest of its processes before the serial device has been confirmed to have initialized correctly.

I would like to change the Serial Init Gui display text without having to destroy and re display the Gui with every new data string from the serial port.

How the text on the Serial Init app is displayed is not important as long as I can read it when necessary. It can be plain text in an otherwise grey window or in a white control.

Comment: _I know I can change the data or text in controls but that is a somewhat unreliable method for long strings of data._  This is the first time I see this comment, why do you say it is unreliable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GuiControl` command to change text controls.

```
GuiControl,, CONTROL_NAME, NEW_TEXT
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank You